# How to check a variable in across multiple arrays in Go

Tags: arrays, go

I've looked up several ways to look through an array in the Go language, but I couldn't find much for searching across multiple arrays. The purpose of my program is to take an input and search across multiple arrays to see if that input is within one of the arrays, and if the term is within one of the arrays, it specifies which array the term was found in. This is my code so far:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := []string{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}
    numbers := arr[26:36]
    letters := arr[0:26]
    fmt.Println(letters)
    vowels := []string{arr[0],arr[4],arr[8],arr[14],arr[20]}
    fmt.Println(arr)
    fmt.Println(numbers)
    fmt.Println(vowels)
    consonants := []string{arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[5],arr[6],arr[7],arr[9],arr[10],arr[11],arr[12],arr[13],arr[15],arr[16],arr[17],arr[18],arr[19],arr[21],arr[22],arr[23],arr[24],arr[25]}
    fmt.Println(consonants)
    odds := []string{numbers[1],numbers[3],numbers[5],numbers[7],numbers[9]}
    fmt.Println(odds)
    evens := []string{numbers[0],numbers[2],numbers[4],numbers[6],numbers[8]}
    fmt.Println(evens)
}
```

If I was to run the program right now through the command prompt, this would be the output:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop>go run Array.go
[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z]
[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[a e i o u]
[b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x y z]
[1 3 5 7 9]
[0 2 4 6 8]
```

To sum up, I need to both take an input, and search the above arrays for where that term may exist. This is what I'd like to have the sample code spit out:

```
Enter term: a
The term "a" was found in array "vowels"
```

Any and all help will do!

Note: The term I keep mentioning is meant to only be a singular letter, or number from 0-9. I also apologize if my code and/or output appears to look sloppy, as I didn't yet have time to clean it up.

Comment: Take a `for` loop and search through those slices.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, most of them terribly simple. Is there something in particular you're after? An example output would probably help tremendously.

Comment: I'm trying to have a user search for a term in the multiple arrays listed above, and have the program print out which array it was found in. I'll edit my post so you can see what I mean. @HeathRaftery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a map with key as the term and value as a slice of term types:

```
m := map[string][]string{}
for _, v := range letters {
    m[v] = append(m[v], "letters")
}
for _, v := range vowels {
    m[v] = append(m[v], "vowels")
}
for _, v := range consonants {
    m[v] = append(m[v], "consonants")
}
for _, v := range numbers {
    m[v] = append(m[v], "numbers")
}
for _, v := range odds {
    m[v] = append(m[v], "odds")
}
for _, v := range evens {
    m[v] = append(m[v], "evens")
}

fmt.Println(m["a"]) // prints [letters vowels]
fmt.Println(m["1"]) // prints [numbers odds]
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1nLrwFoSxjv)

Comment: Thanks for the input! This program is for a class I'm enrolled in, and one of the requirements is the use of an array in the Go language, so I kind of have to keep the arrays in the code. I'll try out the maps and see how it turns out!

Comment: @QFlat that is weird requirement. For one, you are using **slice** instead of array.

Comment: Now is there a way that I can have the user assign a variable to search?

Comment: @QFlat Yes, have a look at `fmt.Scanf` and friends. Homework style questions are difficult to answer because we don't know what you've covered so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, in Go, of ASCII character class tests using arrays.

`charclass.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

const maxASCII = 0x7F

var letters = [maxASCII + 1]bool{
    'a': true, 'b': true, 'c': true, 'd': true, 'e': true, 'f': true, 'g': true,
    'h': true, 'i': true, 'j': true, 'k': true, 'l': true, 'm': true, 'n': true,
    'o': true, 'p': true, 'q': true, 'r': true, 's': true, 't': true, 'u': true,
    'v': true, 'w': true, 'x': true, 'y': true, 'z': true,
}

func isLetter(r rune) bool {
    return (r >= 0 && int(r) < len(letters)) && letters[r|0x20]
}

var vowels = [maxASCII + 1]bool{
    'a': true, 'e': true, 'i': true, 'o': true, 'u': true,
}

func isVowel(r rune) bool {
    return (r >= 0 && int(r) < len(vowels)) && vowels[r|0x20]
}

func isConsonant(r rune) bool {
    return isLetter(r) && !isVowel(r)
}

var numbers = [maxASCII + 1]bool{
    '0': true, '1': true, '2': true, '3': true, '4': true,
    '5': true, '6': true, '7': true, '8': true, '9': true,
}

func isNumber(r rune) bool {
    return (r >= 0 && int(r) < len(numbers)) && numbers[r]
}

func isOddNumber(r rune) bool {
    return isNumber(r) && (r-'0')&1 == 1
}

func isEvenNumber(r rune) bool {
    return isNumber(r) && (r-'0')&1 == 0
}

func main() {
    var classes = []struct {
        name string
        test func(rune) bool
    }{
        {"is a letter", isLetter},
        {"is a consonant", isConsonant},
        {"is a vowel", isVowel},
        {"is a number", isNumber},
        {"is an odd number", isOddNumber},
        {"is an even number", isEvenNumber},
    }

    enter := "Enter a line:"
    fmt.Println(enter)
    s := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for s.Scan() {
        line := s.Text()
        if len(line) == 0 {
            break
        }
        for _, r := range line {
            for _, class := range classes {
                if class.test(r) {
                    fmt.Printf("%q %s\n", r, class.name)
                }
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(enter)
    }
    if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run charclass.go
Enter a line:
QWE asd 12 (*)
'Q' is a letter
'Q' is a consonant
'W' is a letter
'W' is a consonant
'E' is a letter
'E' is a vowel
'a' is a letter
'a' is a vowel
's' is a letter
's' is a consonant
'd' is a letter
'd' is a consonant
'1' is a number
'1' is an odd number
'2' is a number
'2' is an even number
Enter a line:

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below mapping and function for searching keyword categories like "[GO-Play](https://play.golang.org/p/h0MNU7jPUNi)":

```
package main

import "fmt"

var m  = map[string][]string{}

func FindLetterType(search_key string, search_in map[string][]string) (string) {
  return_type := "";
  for type1, keys:= range search_in {
      for _, key:= range keys{
         if(key == search_key){
          return_type = return_type  + "," + type1;
        }
      }
  }
  return return_type ;
}

func main() {
    arr := []string{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}
    numbers := arr[26:36]
    letters := arr[0:26]
    fmt.Println(letters)
    vowels := []string{arr[0],arr[4],arr[8],arr[14],arr[20]}
    fmt.Println(arr)
    fmt.Println(numbers)
    fmt.Println(vowels)
    consonants := []string{arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[5],arr[6],arr[7],arr[9],arr[10],arr[11],arr[12],arr[13],arr[15],arr[16],arr[17],arr[18],arr[19],arr[21],arr[22],arr[23],arr[24],arr[25]}
    fmt.Println(consonants)
    odds := []string{numbers[1],numbers[3],numbers[5],numbers[7],numbers[9]}
    fmt.Println(odds)
    evens := []string{numbers[0],numbers[2],numbers[4],numbers[6],numbers[8]}
    fmt.Println(evens)

for _, v := range letters {
    m["letters"] = append(m["letters"], v)
}
for _, v := range vowels {
    m["vowels"] = append(m["vowels"], v)
}
for _, v := range consonants {
   m["consonants"] = append(m["consonants"], v)
}
for _, v := range numbers {
    m["numbers"] = append(m["numbers"], v)
}
for _, v := range odds {
    m["odds"] = append(m["odds"], v)
}
for _, v := range evens {
   m["evens"] = append(m["evens"], v)
}
//fmt.Println(m);

fmt.Println("a under => ", FindLetterType("a", m));
fmt.Println("a under => ", FindLetterType("1", m));
fmt.Println("a under => ", FindLetterType("2", m));
fmt.Println("a under => ", FindLetterType("b", m));


}
```